# Script Component Won't show all the input columns in the script editor

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a script component that is behaving quite weird, the component's using a Flat File Source has it input column source and I need to output multiple columns to multiple Database tables, the problem is that after connecting the Flat file source and and configuring all the input columns and the multiple output's and output columns and I go into the script editor to configure which output columns gets which input, it won't give me all the Input columns to work, there is a total of  26 columns but it will only let me work with about 20 of the columns so there are 6 columns that are missing and won't let me use them, do you have any idea of what could be causing this???

This images are just to show a little bit about what I'm doing and the problems:

[image: Project]

[image: Input Columns 1]

[image: Input Columns 2]

[image: Input Columns 3]

Comment: Which six columns are missing? What does the Input Columns editor show for those columns? It might just be an artifact of scrolling, but your first screen shot has a checkmark next to the "Name" column indicating all columns are selected. In subsequent shots, it's darkened which normally indicates some, but not all, are selected. You can resize this window, just grab the corner sash and expand. Within the now-big window, pull the sash above input/output/usage type all the way to the top. You ought to be able to see all the columns without scrolling.

Comment: You might also verify your code compiles. Seems unlikely but perhaps bad code is preventing the outer layer from getting all the columns passed in. You can search through `BufferWrapper.cs` once the VSTA project opens for one of your missing columns

Answer (score 0):

I think the Script Component doesn't like columnnames (that start) with a number. They wont show up in Row.[column] as property. Are those columns missing?